# Cmd check for existing path and move after check

Tags: cmd

For a program I have developed I need to check if the program file folder is called Program Files or Program Files (x86) and after that check it has to move files to that path. Or is there an easy way to make it check for IQ Soft Net2 V5 instead of Program files? (I guess that will make it more reliable).

Thanks :)

```
MOVE /Y "C:\Program Files (x86)\IQ Soft Net2 V5\Net2_Data.MDF" "C:\Net2 Access Control\Net2_Data.MDF"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if the environment variable ProgramW6432 is defined

```
@if ["%ProgramW6432%"]==["%ProgramFiles%"] echo %ProgramFiles(x86)%
```

use this in your .cmd-file:

```
REM check 
if not ["%ProgramW6432%"]==[""] ( 
  set pf=%programFiles(x86)%
) else ( 
  set pf=%programfiles% 
)

REM use
move /y "%pf%\IQ Soft Net2 V5\Net2_Data.MDF" "C:\Net2 Access Control\Net2_Data.MDF"
```

Comment: it works but only one thing : the location now is "C:\Program Files \IQsoft\. And the space between Program files and iqsoft gives an error

Comment: Sorry - the third line in the sample code was missing a '%'... I've just made a correction.